# Drupal Site Slow, Drupal Tweaks

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

my site is very slow and i disabled the bulk of modules, so I think it was my hosting, first I upped the memory limit from 90M to 256M which helped with "500 errors" but the site is still very slow. I am thinking it may be the database settings, I am changing them with the module "drupal tweaks" for convenience.

[image: status report screenshot.]

Comment: You have a problem in one/more of your queries that makes it to generate a **lot** of rows (in a temp table on disk or in memory) that is causing you grief.  Review all queries with `join` in them.

Comment: @Johan: What makes you come to that conclusion?  `Max_join_size` is a setting, not status.

Comment: I know you said slowness and having to up the memory so I think joins gone bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "slow".  Is your page slow to appear?  If so, is it taking a while to load the page's HTML, or is much of the time spent trying to load CSS, JS, images, etc.?  The "Net" panel in Firebug can help here, as can `wget`.

If the page itself is slow, is the slowness encountered at the network, Web server, PHP, or database level?  Network slowness is easy to diagnose; try a ping.  Either the network or the web server can show faults through the simple test of just throwing a big, static file somewhere on the server and then downloading it.  PHP or DB slowness will show up when you look at the page with the `devel` module, but DB slowness can generally also be seen as long-running (as opposed to long-`sleep`ing!) processes in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Alternately, give [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) a try.  It will automate several of these steps, and give you fancy graphs, to boot.

Lastly: Consider getting a better hosting provider, ideally one with a great deal of Drupal experience (like [BlackMesh](http://www.blackmesh.com/) or Acquia).  At a great host, fixing this issue (if it arose in the first place) would be a collaborative effort between the hosting provider and the customer, rather than something you have to figure out on your own.  It doesn't take many (billable) hours spent debugging hosting before you've paid for better hosting than you're getting now.

Comment: The speed issue is with the drupal backend cms, commiting to changes.

Comment: i am running windows locally my site dev site is remote hosted, can i use NewRelic?

Comment: NewRelic runs on the machine which you are testing, so if the behavior occurs on the remote dev machine, that's where you'd install it.  The operating system you're running locally is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a staging or development copy of the site, try installing the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), which has an option for logging and appending stats about each query to the bottom of each Drupal page. That should help you track down the offending query or queries.

Comment: Can you use devel on the live site?

Comment: It's not 'recommended' but I've done it plenty of times on live sites and it's never caused a problem (yet!) :)

Comment: if you hav enough memory...go ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some optimisation tips you might try.

1. First it is possible that your cache table should be messed up. Try to log in your phpmyadmin and try to flush all your cache tables (don't delete the tables just empty them).
2. Check inside the MySql installation folders config file alternative like: my-large.ini, my-huge.ini and try to rename them and copy them as bin/my.ini they are out of the box optimisations for your mySQL database.
3. You never mentioned the Drupal version you use. Drupal 7 has a brand new database API build on top of PHP PDO objects.

Here is a link that will help you a lot: http://drupal.org/node/310075

Rather than writing a SQL query in raw text and calling a helper function to execute the query, you can create a "query" object, call methods on it to add fields, filters, sorts, and other query elements, then call the query object's "execute" method.

**Others**

On my website PHP memory limit is 512Mb, 215Mb however should be ok for a production website.

Also why don't you enable APC logging?

Sometimes masive scripts could slow down your pages. in Performance, check your option: agregate CSS and JS file.

you might consider Drupal Pressflow over Drupal.

Boost up your website by installing Boost module: http://drupal.org/project/boost

Cache your Views

Other advanced techniques could include:

Cacherouter ( a module that replace the default Drupal cache).
Using Elysia Cron to reduce cron impact

Eventually switch to a superior hosting package or change your hosting provider

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Drupal site performance is obvious slow, but if its slow to a extreme level then you can go with other options that improved its performance.
1) You can install the memcache module on server,that is very fast in terms of site caching. Refer: [How to install memcache](http://andrewdunkle.com/2012/how-to-install-memcached-for-drupal-7.html)
2) Change the PHP ini settings or mysql conf.
3) Check the custom modules if have, because execution of frequent queries create deadlock.
4) Check the mysql table storage engine & I will recommend the InnoDB which will provide row level locking.